# get route does not redirect

Tags: html, node.js, express, sequelize.js

My code should send the id through a get to the back, there consult the id in the database and thus redirect to the other get route with the record. the intention is that I can fill in text inputs with this record that it will look for in the database.

```
node.js, express, sequelize
app.get("/orcamentos", async (req, res) => {

      //carrega os usuários da database para o front, tornando o html dinâmico.
      try {
         const usuarios = await Usuario.findAll();
         const equipamentos = await Equipamento.findAll();
         const clientes = await Cliente.findAll();
         const matrixs = await Matrix.findAll({

            attributes: matrixColumns,
            order: [['codigo_interno', 'DESC']]
         });

         let cadastros = [];
         if (req.query.cadastros) {
            cadastros = JSON.parse(req.query.cadastros);
         }

         res.render('index', { equipamentos, usuarios, clientes, matrixs, matrixColumns, cadastros});
      } catch (error) {
         console.error('Erro ao buscar usuarios:', error);
         res.status(500).send('Erro interno do servidor');
      };

 });

 app.get("/orcamentos/busca", async (req, res) => {
   try{
      const id = Number(req.query.id);
      const cadastros = await Matrix.findByPk(id);

      if (!cadastros) {
         return res.status(404).send("Cadastro não encontrado");
       }
   
       res.redirect('/orcamentos?cadastros=' + JSON.stringify(cadastros));
     } catch (error) {
       console.error('Erro ao buscar cadastro:', error);
       res.status(500).send('Erro interno do servidor');
     }
 });
```

my html

```
 <div style="overflow: auto;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <% matrixColumns.forEach((matrixColumns) => { %> 
                        <th><%= matrixColumns %></th>
                    <% }); %>
                </tr>
                
                <% matrixs.forEach((matrixs) => { %> 

                    <tr >
                        
                        <% matrixColumns.forEach((column) => { %>

                            <td> <a href="/http://localhost:8080/orcamentos/busca?id=<%= matrixs.codigo_interno %> "> <%= matrixs[column] %> </a> </td>

                        <% }); %>
                            
                    </tr>
                <% }); %>

            </table>
        </div>
```

I would like sequelize to receive the id, do the query, return with the user, so I can redirect to another get route and then use that user in the front-end

Comment: Remove `/http://localhost:8080/` in your href attribute.